# Trigger blur on all inputs Angular2 Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, blur, angular-reactive-forms

I have a very large form with a number of sections represented as separate Form Groups.  At the end of each section I have a check button that checks the validity of all controls within that form group, so far it is as follows

```
checkValidity(g: FormGroup) {
    Object.keys(g.controls).forEach(key => {
      g.get(key).markAsDirty();
    });
    Object.keys(g.controls).forEach(key => {
      g.get(key).markAsTouched();
    });
  }
```

It works fine, but because my generic validator checks and processes validation messages on each controls' input blur event, the validation messages themselves don't pop up until after I focus and blur a control. So I would like to add something to my method above that triggers a blur event on each Form control in a form group, but I haven't been able to figure out how I would do that.

document.getElementById("myAnchor").blur(); from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_blur.asp) shows how I can get element by id and trigger it's blur() that way. Using the method above, would I be able to access all elements in a FormGroup with a forEach to trigger blur on everything? (inputs, textareas, radio buttons and checkboxes)

Please le tme know.

Comment: You can try `document.activeElement.blur()`

Comment: Is there a way I can traverse through all elements of a FormGroup and do so for each one in my above method?

Comment: Nope, FormGroup doesn't have references to elements. They are connected through bridge. There is one way is monkey patching

Comment: How about traversing through the entirety of a document, and if the id/name of an input/textArea contains a substring or something, blur that input/textArea?  Is such a thing possible?  I am absolutely brutal at javascript/typescript.  I'm learning this as I go along for a project at work.

Comment: Monkey patching?

Comment: You could add a directive to all inputs that all listen to a service provided by the component. When an observable in the service emits a specific event, they all call `this.elementRef.nativeElement.blur()`

Comment: I'm reading up on much of what you just said as this is all new to me.  I'll see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured out a solution to this problem just now, and it didn't involve triggering blur or any DOM event.  Having discovered updateValueAndValidity() for a previous problem, I called it on each control in the form group exactly the same way I marked all controls as dirty and touched in the question.  Demonstrated below.

```
  checkValidity(g: FormGroup) {
Object.keys(g.controls).forEach(key => {
  g.get(key).markAsDirty();
});
Object.keys(g.controls).forEach(key => {
  g.get(key).markAsTouched();
});
Object.keys(g.controls).forEach(key => {
  g.get(key).updateValueAndValidity();
});
}
```

This properly displays the validation error messages under each control in the form group, where previously I would have to focus and then blur on any control for this to happen.